# How to redirect from a 3rd level nested route to the 3rd param if user manually modifies the url & hits Enter in react-router-dom-6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following basic example taken from the official `react-router-dom` github page and adjusted:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="parent/:id">
      <Route index element={<FirstChild />} />
      <Route path=":source" element={<SecondChild />} />
    </Route>

    <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

and the layout

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li>
       <Link to="/">Home</Link>
     </li>
     <li>
       <Link to="/about">About</Link>
     </li>
     <li>
       <Link to="/parent/2">FirstChild</Link>
     </li>
     <li>
       <Link to="/parent/2/editor">SecondChild</Link>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

So when I hit `SecondChild` route link I navigate to `myDomain/parent/2/editor`.
What I would like to achieve is in case the user goes manually in the browser url and erases or modifies the last param, which in my case is `editor`. If the users writes `editor2` and hits ENTER, how do I redirect the user to `myDomain/parent/2/editor`? Does anyone know if this is possible in `react-router-dom@6`?

[Demo to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hodgkin-s6ejtp?file=/src/App.js:643-649)

**Edit**

`source` is dynamic. So there are other pages with the route "/parent/:id/...". There is for instance

```
/parent/:id/labelbook
```

And I want to redirect to the correct route in case user modifies again labelbook or editor in the two different scenarios to the correct route param. In the future a third scenario maybe will be added.
In react `router-dom 5` I could do that by adding `?` next to the param but now this is gone. I could do

```
<Route path=":source?" element={<SecondChild />} />
```

and get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a redirect at that nested level.

First, since it's unclear *what* exactly you want to render at the second nested level I'll provide a couple examples.

Example #1: The `SecondChild` component is rendered exactly on `"/parent/:id/editor"` and you want to redirect *any other* nested route to there.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="parent/:id">
      <Route index element={<FirstChild />} />
      <Route path="editor" element={<SecondChild />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="../editor" replace />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Example #2: The `SecondChild` component is rendered on `"/parent/:id/:source"` and you ***explicitly*** want to redirect from `"/parent/:id/editor2"` to `"/parent/:id/editor"`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="parent/:id">
      <Route index element={<FirstChild />} />
      <Route path=":source" element={<SecondChild />} />
      <Route
        path="editor2"
        element={<Navigate to="../editor" replace />}
      />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Example #3:
If you've a list of *specific* `":source"` values you want to match then you should render explicit routes for each. If the `SecondChild` component *depends* on what a "source" value is then I'd suggest passing it in as a prop. Any route that isn't explicitly matched will be rendered to the `"*"` `NoMatch` route.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="parent/:id">
      <Route index element={<FirstChild />} />
      <Route path="editor" element={<SecondChild source="editor" />} />
      <Route path="labelbook" element={<SecondChild source="labelbook" />} />
      ... etc ...
    <Route path="*" element={<NoMatch />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: +1. Sorry I did not clarify it well maybe, `source` is dynamic. So there are other pages with the route "/parent/:id/...". There is for instance `"/parent/:id/labelbook"`. The issue arises due to the fact that source is name agnostic. I don't know if now is edit or later labelbook. Therefore the user maybe in one of the two scenarios and tries to change the url manually. As a result I cannot afford doing that `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="../editor" replace />} />` for every single case separately.

Comment: @kboul The first example is a "catch-all", but I think the second example is likely more what you are looking for. If a user somehow navigates to `"/parent/:id/editor2"` the redirect will bounce them to the `"editor"` segment and the `":source"` route will handle it and assign the value of `"editor"` to the `source` route path param.

Comment: @kboul I'm going to guess next though that perhaps you are ***not*** asking about how to redirect from/to specific routes (*i.e. "../editor2", "../editor4", etc...*) and the real underlying question you have is about validating the `source` param. For this you'll just need to have the single `":source"` route rendering `SecondChild` and you'll need to validate the parameter manually in the component.

Comment: So I guess it is not possible to do it in the route declaration. `:source` is dynamic. I gave an example with `editor` but it can be anything. Otherwise I would declare it in the first place as `/parent/:id/editor` and `/parent/:id/labelbook` but it is the same component with adjusted functionality.

Comment: @kboul Does the `SecondChild` component need to now what the `source` route param value is?

Comment: I will have to check that tomorrow and come back. I suspect that you may have a good point here and I will have to implement your 3rd example. I will let you know tomorrow.

Comment: So, the 3rd solution is really close to what I am looking for, however there are a bunch of components children of `SecondChild` using a hook which calls source from `useParams`. So if I follow the 3rd approach I will have to prop drill everywhere source prop which I think is overkill.

Comment: @kboul Are you saying that `SecondChild` needs to "props drill" the `source` prop down a few levels to a more deeply nested descendent component? If so, use a React context to pass it down outside of props.

Comment: Yes correct. That would be one solution I guess...

Comment: Ok thanks, I ended up doing the same with redux instead of context as we already leverage it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @kboul Ah yeah, Redux is basically the ultimate version of the [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) pattern. Happy to help. Cheers and good luck!